# Android SDK Manager stuck on fetching repo

Tags: android, adt, fetch

I just installed androidsdk (revision 22.3) aka adt for windows as I'm on Win7.

After opening the SDKManager it always keeps on "Fetching http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml"

Btw. I'm NOT behind a proxy.

I already tried:

- setting option to force https to be fetched using http
- running sdkmanager as administrator
- reinstalling androidsdk (adt)

Nothing helped..any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I am running the newest version of Android SDK manager on macOS and have the exact same problem. Seems this problem from 2014 is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In SDK Manager. Go to Options, Set
HTTP Proxy server: www.google.com
Port:  80
And tick "Force https://............"